# BDD Java/Serenity/Cucumber, how to connect a page without default url?

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber, bdd, serenity-bdd

When creating a page how can i use not defaultURL but dynamic one? 
My url uses numbering depending one the object i select. 
In the example below is "2". My question is how can  i link it with a number in the Feature file where the user of the automation test will require the proper number so also page.

@DefaultUrl("http://develop.example.testexample.tool.com/#/triggers/**2**/add")
@At("#HOST/#/2/triggers/add")

Answer (score 0):

For you to test this page you need to be able to create the underlying object which has the id that makes up the dynamic part of your URL. In this case your trigger. You can retrieve the trigger and use its ID to make your URL.

So with Cucumber you might have something like

`Given I have a trigger
When I view the triggers add page
...`

And you could implement that with something like

```
Given 'I have a trigger' do
  @trigger = create_trigger
end

When 'I view the triggers add page' do
  visit trigger_add_page_path(trigger: @trigger)
end
```

Notice how the variable created in the Given is used in the When.

You'll have to work out your language/platform specifics that allow you to get this working, but hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand what you propose. What is actually my problem is that i want to pass instead of "2" a variable, because the url at this place, changes depending on link i used before. 

If i choose another link could be the same url but with 4

@DefaultUrl("http://develop.example.testexample.tool.com/#/triggers/4/add") 

i know from before what is the number, but i want to connect with my features file so to use it for every test case (1,2,3,4,5 etc)

Comment: You have to understand how the link is formed, i.e. how the dynamic part of the link is created. This has to be based on something in the system. You can either create that thing in a Given, or if it already exists calculate what the dynamic thing will be by loading and examining the thing.

Comment: Yes you are right. I know exactly who it is created. What i miss is how to in pages. make it depending on the input i give in the feautre file. I use java/serenity and the closest i see now is macros which actually transform my url

Comment: https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/blob/master/serenity-core/src/main/java/net/serenitybdd/core/pages/MatchingPageExpressions.java